# Disable Sublist schedule

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript2.0

I trying an HIDDEN sublist (quantity), an it's work. but but when i try DISABLE, sublist not disable.
my code looks like

```
define(['N/ui/serverWidget'], function(serverWidget) {
function readOnlyFields(params){
          try
            {
                var form = params.form;
     
                var sublistObj = form.getSublist({
                    id: 'item'
                });
                
                
                var subs1 = sublistObj.getField({
                    id: 'quantity'
                });
                subs1.updateDisplayType({
                    displayType : serverWidget.FieldDisplayType.DISABLED
                });
            }
           catch(e)
           {
                 // you message in case of error
            }
        }
return {
        beforeLoad: readOnlyFields
    };
});
```

[image: Sublist and schedule]

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code on 'Sales Order' and 'Item Fulfillment', and is working. The field was disabled.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmV5h.png)

Comment: Yes, but i try at transfer order disable quantity its not respond